# Для заголовков(h1, h2 ......) не работаю установленные шрифты

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Всем привет. Я установил на сайт свой шрифт. Прописал его для тега SPAN и текст отобразился нужным шрифтом. Проделал такое же но с h3 - результат нулевой, то есть шрифт не применился к тексту внутри заголовка. Почему?

Comment: А покажите css-код, который вы используете

Comment: ммм, изза вспышек на сольнце и уменьшения озонового слоя земли. 
"у меня не работает холодильник! Почему?"   
а чего, угадывать что вы там написали? код покажите)

Comment: @font-face
{
    font-family: ProunX Bold;  src:         url(http://cmstemplate/img/fonts/ProunX_Bold.ttf);  
}
.left_navigation h3
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'ProunX Bold', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

Comment: ProunX Bold в ковычки возьмите. т.е. должно получится 
@font-face { font-family: 'ProunX Bold'; src: url(http://cmstemplate/img/fonts/ProunX_Bold.ttf);
} .left_navigation h3 { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: 'ProunX Bold', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; }